# macOS size command shows a really large number?

Tags: macos, unix

```
> size /bin/ls
__TEXT  __DATA  __OBJC  others  dec hex
20480   4096    0   4294983680  4295008256  10000a000
```

How could it be that `ls` is 4GB? Is `size` not meant to be used on executables? I have 4GB ram, so is it just showing me the amount memory it can use?

Comment: You should have tried `man size` before asking such a question

Comment: I get the same output on a Mac running macOS 10.14.4 Mojave with 16 GiB main memory, so (a) the numbers are valid and (b) it isn't a question of the memory available.      The 'dec' size is the sum of the 'text', 'data', 'objc' and 'others' sizes.  The mystery is why the 'others' size is so huge.  I don't have a good explanation.  Neither does the manual page, AFAICS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On macOS, 64-bit apps have a 4GB page zero, by default. Page zero is chunk of the address space starting at address 0 which allows no access. This is what causes access violations when a program dereferences a null pointer.

64-bit Mac programs use a 4GB page zero so that, should any valid pointer get accidentally truncated to 32 bits by a program bug (e.g. cast to `int` and back to a pointer), it will be invalid and cause a crash as soon as possible. That helps to find and fix such bugs.

The page zero segment in the Mach-O executable file doesn't actually use 4GB on disk. It's just a bit of metadata that tells the kernel and dynamic loader how much address space to reserve for it. It seems that `size` is including the virtual size of all segments, regardless of whether they take up space on disk or not.

Also, the page zero doesn't consume actual RAM when the program is loaded, either. Again, there's just some bookkeeping data to track the fact that the lower 4GB of the address space is reserved.

The size being reported for "others", 4294983680 bytes, is `0x100004000` in hex. That's the 4GB page zero (`0x100000000`) plus another 4 pages for some other segments.

You can use the `-m` option to `size` to get more detail:

```
$ size -m /bin/ls
Segment __PAGEZERO: 4294967296
Segment __TEXT: 20480
    Section __text: 13599
    Section __stubs: 456
    Section __stub_helper: 776
    Section __const: 504
    Section __cstring: 1150
    Section __unwind_info: 148
    total 16633
Segment __DATA: 4096
    Section __got: 40
    Section __nl_symbol_ptr: 16
    Section __la_symbol_ptr: 608
    Section __const: 552
    Section __data: 40
    Section __bss: 224
    Section __common: 140
    total 1620
Segment __LINKEDIT: 16384
total 4295008256
```

You can also use the command `otool -lV /bin/ls` to see the loader commands of the executable, including the one establishing the `__PAGEZERO` segment.

Answer (score 0):

The `size` command outputs information related to some binary [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) and how it is running. It is *not* about the file. The 4Gb number might be (that is just my guess) related to the [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) needed to run it.

I don't have a MacOSX operating system (because it is proprietary and tied to hardware that I dislike and find too expensive). But on Linux (which is mostly [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX), like MacOSX), `size /bin/ls` gives:

```
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
 124847    4672    4824  134343   20cc7 /bin/ls
```

while `ls -l /bin/ls` shows

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 138856 Feb 28 16:30 /bin/ls
```

Of course, when `ls` is running, it has some data (notably [bss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss)) which is not corresponding to a part of the executable

Try `man size` on your system to get an explanation. For Linux, see [size(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/size.1.html) (it gives info about *sections* of an [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) executable) and [ls(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html) (it gives the *file* size).

On MacOSX, executables follow the [Mach-O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach-O) format.

On Linux, if you try `size` on a non-executable file such as `/etc/passwd`, you get

```
 size: /etc/passwd: file format not recognized
```

and I guess that you should have some error message on MacOSX if you try that.

Think of `size` giving *executable* size information. The name is historical and a bit misleading.